# Building a Mongo query using rails? How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

This is how I went about to query for one specific element.

```
results << read_db.collection("users").find(:created_at => {:$gt => initial_date}).to_a
```

Now, I am trying to query by more than one.

```
db.inventory.find({ $and: [ { price: 1.99 }, { qty: { $lt: 20 } }, { sale: true } ] } )
```

Now how do I build up my query? Essentially I will have have a bunch of if statements, if true, i want to extend my query. I heard there is a .extend command in another langue, is there something similar in ruby?

Essentially i want to do this:

```
if price
query = "{ price: 1.99 }"
end

if qty
query = query + "{ qty: { $lt: 20 } }"
end
```

and than just have

```
 db.inventory.find({ $and: [query]})
```

This syntax is wrong, what is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to end up with something like this:

```
db.inventory.find({ :$and => some_array_of_mongodb_queries})
```

Note that I've switched to the hashrocket syntax, you can't use the JavaScript notation with symbols that aren't labels. The value for `:$and` should be an array of individual queries, not an array of strings; so you should build an array:

```
parts = [ ]
parts.push(:price => 1.99)         if(price)
query.push(:qty => { :$lt => 20 }) if(qty)
#...
db.inventory.find(:$and => parts)
```

BTW, you might run into some floating point problems with `:price => 1.99`, you should probably use an integer for that and work in cents instead of dollars. Some sort of check that `parts` isn't empty might be a good idea too.

Comment: quick question. How do i push an empty query? $and can't have only one or no entries

Comment: If `parts.empty?` then you have nothing to search for, if `parts.size == 1` then you can skip the `:$and` and use `parts.first` directly: `db.inventory.find(parts.first)`

Comment: awesome. Thank you! How would i say search all? If empty search all. 

All of these are working so far! I am making big progress, thanks again

Comment: You should be able to say `db.inventory.find()` to get them all.